# Precompute Functions for use in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, special-functions

I have a very complicated pair of functions $F(x,y), G(x,y)$ that are used in a differential equation
$0 = x'' + F(x,y)$,  $0 =y '' + G(x,y)\,. $
$F$ and $G$ are roughly sums of products of the Bessel functions $J_n(x) J_m(y)$. In a differential equation, it is very costly to have to recompute the sum of these special functions at each step. Is there a way to make this process more efficient? I would like, for example, to precompute an interpolating function for use in NDSolve but I find NDSolve has trouble with these types of functions.

Comment: If you sample the functions and fit them with the option `Method->"Splines"` it typically works well the `NDSolve` from my limited experience.

Answer (score 0):

`NDSolve` does not have problems with interpolating functions. Not from my experience at least. Can you post an example where you run into problems?

A few other thoughts:

- Are you by any chance using `BesselJZero` in $F$ and $G$ (`BesselJZero` is even slower than `BesselJ`)
- Bessel functions have other parametrizations which you could try
- [Try using `Compile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214807/how-to-speed-up-this-code-with-bessel-functions)
- [Check this question: How to improve performance of BesselJ to the level of GSL?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84982/how-to-improve-performance-of-besselj-to-the-level-of-gsl)